# how can i scroll recyclerview in bottomsheet，but bottomsheet not to slide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bs_bg_shape_corner"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[this is what i want for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeK98.jpg)

How can I scroll recyclerview in bottomsheet，but bottomsheet should stay fixed?

Answer (score -1):

In your bottomsheet view:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

And in your recyclerview:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

The goal is to prevent the recyclerview from passing the touch event up to its parent.

Here is my XML (verified working). I am not using a RV, but my chart view is able to pan and not close the drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <import type="com.example.data.models.pojo.TrackerSettings" />

    <variable name="frag" type="com.example.ui.app.tracker.TrackerFragment" />

</data>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/graph_sheet"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.ui.widgets.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/peak"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/animIconGraph"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/top_rounded"
                android:backgroundTint="#aaaaaa"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/anim_graph"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
                android:onClick="@{() -> frag.onGraphIconTapped()}"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/top_left_rounded"
            android:backgroundTint="#aaaaaa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50"/>


        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry，why do you not to try use recyclerview。。。is not work